# I am getting error while running ionic project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I want to run ionic project but getting error like below:
I have run command as `ng serve --port=8100`
this is my command prompt error:

` E:\IonicProj\Moodle IOS\Moodle>ng serve --port=8100
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(stylePreprocessorOptions).
E:\IonicProj\Moodle IOS\Moodle\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\hostReportError.js:4
setTimeout(function () { throw err; }, 0);
^

SchemaValidationException [Error]: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(stylePreprocessorOptions).
at MapSubscriber.project (E:\IonicProj\Moodle IOS\Moodle\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect.js:42:27)
at MapSubscriber._next (E:\IonicProj\Moodle IOS\Moodle\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:49:35)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (E:\IonicProj\Moodle IOS\Moodle\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (E:\IonicProj\Moodle IOS\Moodle\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:205:16)
at SafeSubscriber.next (E:\IonicProj\Moodle IOS\Moodle\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:143:22)
at Subscriber._next (E:\IonicProj\Moodle IOS\Moodle\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:89:26)
at Subscriber.next (E:\IonicProj\Moodle IOS\Moodle\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (E:\IonicProj\Moodle IOS\Moodle\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:205:16)
at SafeSubscriber.next (E:\IonicProj\Moodle IOS\Moodle\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:143:22)
at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (E:\IonicProj\Moodle IOS\Moodle\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:93:26) {
errors: [
{
instancePath: '',
schemaPath: '#/additionalProperties',
keyword: 'additionalProperties',
params: { additionalProperty: 'stylePreprocessorOptions' },
message: 'must NOT have additional properties'
}
]
} `

I have run command as "ionic serve". this is prints continuously line "[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with npm..."
This is my ionic info:

` Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 7.1.1 (C:\Users\user101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 15.2.8
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 15.2.8
@angular/cli                  : 15.2.8
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.0.0

Capacitor:

Capacitor CLI      : 5.2.3
@capacitor/android : 5.2.3
@capacitor/core    : 5.2.3
@capacitor/ios     : not installed

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0 (cordova-lib@10.1.0)
Cordova Platforms : not available
Cordova Plugins   : not available

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.15.4
native-run  : 1.7.2

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\itt-sooraj\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
NodeJS            : v16.14.2 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm               : 9.5.0
OS                : Windows 10 `

This is my angular information:
` Angular CLI: 15.2.8
Node: 16.14.2
Package Manager: npm 9.5.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 15.2.8
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router `
| Package                        | Version   |
| -------------------------------|------------
| @angular-devkit/architect      | 0.1101.2  |
| @angular-devkit/build-angular  | 15.2.8    |
| @angular-devkit/core           | 15.2.8    |
| @angular-devkit/schematics     | 15.2.8    |
| @angular/language-service      | 10.0.14   |
| @schematics/angular            | 15.2.8    |
| rxjs                           | 7.4.0     |
| typescript                     | 4.9.5     |

I have updated my ionic, npm and node versions.

I have tried lot's of command in command prompt but yet not not succeeded.
I have run below commands :
`ionic serve ng serve --port=8100`

but still can not run my code.

Here is my angular.json file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "defaultProject": "app",
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "www",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "src/theme/theme.scss"
              }
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": false,
                "styles":{
                  "minify": false,
                  "inlineCritical": true
                  } 
              },
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true, 
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "50mb",
                  "maximumError": "100mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build",
            "disableHostCheck": true,
            "port": 8100
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
                "src/**/*.ts",
                "src/core/**/*.html",
                "src/addons/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        },
        "ionic-cordova-build": {
          "builder": "@ionic/angular-toolkit:cordova-build",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "ionic-cordova-serve": {
          "builder": "@ionic/angular-toolkit:cordova-serve",
          "options": {
            "cordovaBuildTarget": "app:ionic-cordova-build",
            "devServerTarget": "app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "cordovaBuildTarget": "app:ionic-cordova-build:production",
              "devServerTarget": "app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@ionic/angular-toolkit",
    "analytics": "7477caff-90f8-43b7-804c-487c01487e0b"
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:page": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with my project when first setting it up. In the first part of the error message it says you must not have `stylePreprocessorOptions` as an additional property. (See below)

` E:\IonicProj\Moodle IOS\Moodle>ng serve --port=8100 Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(stylePreprocessorOptions).

Search for `stylePreprocessorOptions` in your project and remove it from any files. It should just be in the angular.json if I remember correctly.

Comment: I removed it now getting error as:

./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
E:/DataIonic/Moodle IOS/Moodle/src/core/features/editor/components/rich-text-editor/rich-text-editor.scss:17:100: ERROR: Unterminated string token

Comment: the error " ERROR: Unterminated string token " is showing always with different files like rich-text-editor.scss, course.scss, ramdomly showing my all scss files. 
please let me know what will be exact sollution for it.

Comment: Can you update your question with your angular.json file? I have a feeling this is coming from an issue in there and so it is breaking the initial styles compilation/injection.